# Secure auth with Node.js, GraphQL, Nexus and passport with JWT's

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization, jwt, graphql

I am trying to authenticate / authorise users with graphql, nexus, passport, prisma, graphql-shield and fastify for REST with JWT

To answer possible questions: I am using passport because it handles the callbacks for me in a nice way, I could create something fully tied to my mutations and remove everything REST related but it's not going to look pretty, also I need to support apple auth, SMS and email so writing custom auth flows for them will be a lot of code

In the frontend I would use apollo graphql and use the refresh token to get a access token from the refresh_token route, the refresh token would be saved in a variable

This is a single API to serve a React website that uses the currently implemented google auth and a React native app for the other auth methods I mentioned earlier, I would implement the other auth options in a similar way

I am not asking for a review on code style, I would love feedback on the auth flow and know for sure that this is a safe way of doing auth

```
// index.ts
import "./passport"

const main = () => {
  const server = fastify({ logger })
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: applyMiddleware(schema, permissions),
    context: (request: Omit<Context, "prisma">) => ({ ...request, prisma }),
    tracing: __DEV__,
  })

  server.register(fastifyCookie)
  server.register(apolloServer.createHandler())
  server.register(fastifyPassport.initialize())

  server.get(
    "/auth/google",
    {
      preValidation: fastifyPassport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["profile", "email"],
        session: false,
      }),
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
    async () => {}
  )

  server.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    {
      preValidation: fastifyPassport.authorize("google", { session: false }),
    },
    async (request, reply) => {
      // Store user in database
      // const user = existingOrCreatedUser
      // sendRefreshToken(user, reply)
      // const accessToken = createAccessToken(user)
      // reply.send({ accessToken, user })
    }
  )
      
  server.get("/refresh_token", async (request, reply) => {
    const token = request.cookies.fid

    if (!token) {
      return reply.send({ accessToken: "" })
    }

    let payload

    try {
      payload = verify(token, secret)
    } catch {
      return reply.send({ accessToken: "" })
    }

    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: payload.userId },
    })

    if (!user) {
      return reply.send({ accessToken: "" })
    }

    if (user.tokenVersion !== payload.tokenVersion) {
      return reply.send({ accessToken: "" })
    }

    sendRefreshToken(user, reply)

    return reply.send({ accessToken: createAccessToken(user) })
  })

  server.listen(port)
}
```

```
// passport.ts
import fastifyPassport from "fastify-passport"
import { OAuth2Strategy } from "passport-google-oauth"

fastifyPassport.registerUserSerializer(async (user) => user)
fastifyPassport.registerUserDeserializer(async (user) => user)

fastifyPassport.use(
  new OAuth2Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback",
    },
    (_accessToken, _refreshToken, profile, done) => done(undefined, profile)
  )
)
```

```
// permissions/index.ts
import { shield } from "graphql-shield"
import { rules } from "./rules"

export const permissions = shield({
  Mutation: {
    createOneShopLocation: rules.isAuthenticatedUser,
  },
})
```

````
// permissions/rules.ts
import { rule } from "graphql-shield"
import { Context } from "../context"

export const rules = {
  isAuthenticatedUser: rule()(async (_parent, _args, ctx: Context) => {
    const authorization = ctx.request.headers.authorization

    if (!authorization) {
      return false
    }

    try {
      const token = authorization.replace("Bearer", "")
      const payload = verify(token, secret)

      // mutative
      ctx.payload = payload

      return true
    } catch {
      return false
    }
  }),
}
```
````